# How do you install a file to site-packages (not package sub-folder) from setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools

**General problem:**
Is there a way in setuptools to have a dll installed in the prefix\Lib\site-packages directory?

**My specific need:**
PyQt5 doesn't provide a binary installer for Python2.7, so I've built from source and I'd like to package the result for convenience.  The official installer puts sip.pyd in prefix\Lib\site-packages, and I'd like to be consistent.  But I'm not sure how.  It seems I can use py_modules or ext_modules and define where I want the module to go, but I can't figure out how to make either of those work with a .pyd file.

I'm concerned about windows, but I *think* if there is a setuptools solution, it would be platform independent.  If it matters, I'm trying to deploy as a wheel (.whl) file.

Here's what I have:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension

setup(name='PyQt5',
      version='5.2',
      packages=find_packages(),
      package_data = {"PyQt5":["*.pyd","uic/widget-plugins/*.py"]},
      include_package_data=True,
      scripts=["sip.exe"],
      #ext_modules=[Extension("sip.pyd", ["sip.pyd"])], # <- this isn't working
      headers=["sip.h"],
      classifiers=[
        'Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License (GPL)',
      ],
      )
```

Just so I'm clear, here's what the PyQt4 installer packaging looks like:
[image: PyQt4 installer structure]

You can see that instead of being put in $_OUTDIR, sip.pyd goes to Lib\site-packages.

Comment: It should go into that location by default, have you tried it?

Comment: Most of the "stuff" goes in a PyQt5 *subdirectory* in site-packages.  I'm looking for a way to put sip.pyd in the site-packages directory itself, not the PyQt5 folder.

Comment: As a workaround hack, you could call `os.rename` to move the file to the correct location after calling `setup`.  Not a solution I know.

Comment: If you are compiling the `.pyd` file, then `ext_modules=[Extension("sip.pyd", ["path/to/sip.pyd"])]` will put the compiled `sip.pyd` to site packages. If you want do distribute an already compiled `sip.pyd` in a wheel, then you can put the file into site packages root via `data_files` arg.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly this is a hack, but it gets the job done for us.  We have different shared objects based on platform, and don't have the luxury of being able to build them on all platforms.  So we keep them in compiled form in the git repo.

Right after you call `setup(...)` in your setup.py file.

```
def copydir(source, dest):
    for fname in os.listdir(source):                                                                                                                                                             
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(source, fname), os.path.join(dest, fname))                                                                                                                      

if os.path.isfile('/etc/redhat-release') and platform.system() == "Linux":                                                                                                                       
    copydir('redhat', 'modname')                                                                                                                                                              
elif platform.system() == "Windows":                                                                                                                                                             
    copydir('windows', 'modname')                                                                                                                                                             
else:                                                                                                                                                                                            
    copydir('debian', 'modname')
```

Comment: This will only work if you run "python setup.py install" with a source distro, right?